# Linear Independence of Large Sparse Matrices in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, large-data

I have three large matrices: I, G, and G^2. These are 4Million x 4Million matrices and they are sparse. I would like to check if they are linearly independent and I would like to do this in R.

For small matrices, a way to this is to vectorize each matrix: stack columns on top of each other and test if the matrix formed by the three stacked vectors has rank three.

However, due to the size of my problem I am not sure how to proceed.

(1) Is there a way to vectorize a Large Sparse Matrix into a Very Large Sparse Vector in R?

(2) Is there any other solution to the problem that could make this test efficient ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting your matrices to vectors, you can keep only the non-zero elements.

```
# Sample data
n <- 4e6
k <- n
library(Matrix)
I <- spMatrix(n, n, 1:n, 1:n, rep(1,n))
G <- spMatrix(n, n, 
  sample(1:n, k, replace=TRUE), 
  sample(1:n, k, replace=TRUE), 
  sample(0:9, k, replace=TRUE)
)
G2 <- G %*% G
G2 <- as(G2, "dgTMatrix")  # For the j slot

# Only keep elements that are non-zero in one of the 3 matrices
i <- as.integer( c(G@i, G2@i, I@i) + 1 )
j <- as.integer( c(G@j, G2@j, I@j) + 1 )
ij <- cbind(i,j)
rankMatrix( cbind( G2[ij], G[ij], I[ij] ) ) # 3

# Another example
m <- ceiling(n/2)-1
G <- spMatrix(n, n,
  c(1:n, 2*(1:m)),
  c(1:n, 2*(1:m)+1),
  rep(1, n+m)
)
G2 <- as(G %*% G, "dgTMatrix")
i <- c(G@i, G2@i, I@i) + 1
j <- c(G@j, G2@j, I@j) + 1
ij <- cbind(i,j)
rankMatrix( cbind( G2[ij], G[ij], I[ij] ) ) # 2
```

(To speed things up, you could take only a small part of those vectors: 
if the rank is already 3, you know that they are independent,
if it is 2, you can check if the linear dependence relation also holds for the large vectors.)

Comment: Exactly what i wanted ! Thank you so much !

Comment: I am facing a problem with the ij <- cbind(i,j) operation. For some of my matrices, R complains that the vector is too large. Any ideas ?

Comment: Making sure that the indices are integers reduces the memory usage, 
but just by a factor two: this may not be sufficient.